# ArrayList Double

Tags: arraylist, double

Im getting this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "-20.528899,"
```

im using a webservice to get latitude and longitude from bd, and show in a map.
I am not able to pass the latitude and longitude values to list
i am saving lat and long at the same column in db, so this field should be "lat, long" eg "-20.528899, -47.438933" and i need to parse this in the list...can i do this?

```
public List<Localizacoes> buscarLocalizacoes(){

    List<Localizacoes> lista = new ArrayList<Localizacoes>();

    SoapObject buscarLocalizacoes = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, BUSCAR);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarLocalizacoes);

    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        http.call("uri:" + BUSCAR, envelope);

        Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

        for (SoapObject soapObject : resposta){
            Localizacoes loc = new Localizacoes();

            loc.setId(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("id").toString()));
            loc.setNome(soapObject.getProperty("nome").toString());
            loc.setDescricao(soapObject.getProperty("descricao").toString());
            loc.setPosicao(soapObject.getProperty("posicao").toString()); // error in this line

            lista.add(loc);
        }

    }  catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return lista;
}
```

activity

```
dao = new LocalizacoesDAO(context);
    List<Localizacoes> lista = dao.buscarLocalizacoes();

    Log.d("Teste Buscar", lista.toString());

 public void setPosicao(LatLng poLatLng) {
    this.poLatLng = poLatLng;
    this.posicao = String.valueOf(poLatLng.latitude) + " " + String.valueOf(poLatLng.longitude);
}

public void setPosicao(String posicao) {
    this.posicao = posicao;
    String[] pos = posicao.split(" ");
    this.poLatLng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(pos[0]), Double.valueOf(pos[1]));
}
```

can anyone help me pls?

Comment: You have a comma in your string... "-20.528899," (See before the end ")

Comment: yeah, i am saving lat and long at the same column in db, so this field should be "lat, long" eg "-20.528899, -47.438933" and i need to parse this in the list...can i do this?

Comment: Share setPosicao methof

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace? Where `parseDouble` is called, in `setPosicao`? Anyway, try split result and set values to position.

Comment: Edited whith setPosicao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line in your setPosicao(String) method

```
String[] pos = posicao.split(" ");
```

**INTO**

```
String[] pos = posicao.split(", ");
```

(Since you have a ',' and a ' ' in the string)

Comment: You are very welcome and sorry for the typo. I posted the answer from the mobile app so I wasn't able to structure it properly.